# How exactly do you enter the twilight?

Tags: night-watch-cycle

As an other it is possible to "pick up your shadow" and enter the twilight. In doing this the first time, you get initiated. Is a more precise description to be found on this procedure?

Comment: The description does not necessarily have to come from the books from Lukyanenko. Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Hmm, I feel like it would be like describing how someone jumps etc. For example it was possible to only look into Twilight.

Comment: Thanks for the first input on this. This is appreciated very much. As an information from the books, I think it is possible to _glance_ into the twilight, after you have been initiated. Could be, that those two procedures are similar though. Anyways I also think, that it is possible to describe, how someone jumps. So please, if you have some information on this (refering to my question, not to jumping), do hesitate to share it, even if it is just like describing how to jump. Again: thanks for the first comment on this.

Comment: Sorry - misspelled, of course: do **not** hesitate to share it, ...